# Write a patent without giving too much away

Tags: software, patent-applications, writing

I would like to acquire a patent for a software algorithm, but I don't want to provide too much detail, for fear that anyone could look it up, and copy the steps that I've outlined.

Answer (score 4):

If you are afraid "anyone could look it up" - IMO you are better off treating it as a trade secret - please check this link for details http://www.wipo.int/sme/en/ip_business/trade_secrets/patent_trade.htm

Also one other thing about "acquire a patent for a software algorithm" - in view of the recent [Alice ruling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_Int%27l) , I would encourage you to consult a Patent Attorney to understand the efficacy of protecting your software algorithm with a Patent.